# How to hide elements on a website in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I want to load this page on a Webview but I want to hide this header element with search bar and logo. I don't know much about Javascript, is there a way to do this?

this is the part I want to hide

[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for a solution using javascript.
you can copy the below script and excute through chrome inspect. ( Ctrl + Shift + i
, go to `Console` tab, paste the below script and press enter.)

```
document.getElementById("searchform").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("sfcnt").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("top_nav").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("appbar").style.display = "none";
```

[image]

What am I doing is actually the same as other's answer, change those unwanted div's CSS style as `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
#sfcnt, #top_nav, #appbar { display: none }
```

It will break if they change it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display property in css style sheet to hide stuff that you want.

```
element{
display:none;
}
```

here element can be anything(i.e body, *, div, navbar).

Comment: the question is about javascript. Not CSS.